# Facebook Share opens new instance of an App - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, fbsdksharekit

I am using Facebook iOS SDK and FBSDKShareLinkContent for sharing url and image with text. Everything seems OK while sharing. But the problem is after sharing, the new instance of app is opened. The one sharing has been done is still open in background.

Is there something am I doing wrong? How to avoid it?

Here is the code I am using for sharing...

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentDescription = [[MusicPlayerHelper playerManager] getTextToShare];
content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[MusicPlayerHelper playerManager] getURLToShare]];
content.imageURL=[NSURL URLWithString:[[MusicPlayerHelper playerManager] getImageURLToShare]];

FBSDKShareDialog *dialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fbauth2://"]]){
    dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeNative;
}
else {
    dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeAutomatic; //or FBSDKShareDialogModeAutomatic
}

dialog.shareContent = content;
dialog.delegate = _delegate;
dialog.fromViewController = _delegate;
[dialog show];
```

Comment: Did you test this on iOS 10 or iOS 9? I'm seeing similar behaviour when I upgraded my device to iOS 10.